# Google Sheets SUMIFS different criteria with checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i've the following formula the problem i've is, this isn't working as it should be.

```
=SUMIFS(E9:14,$I$16:$I,FALSE(),$H$16:$H,G8)
```

E9:E14 is the part which should be summed up when the checkbox in I16:I = FALSE and if the name matches in H16:H from G8. My problem is I am getting this error

```
The array arguments of "SUMIFS" vary in size
```

My question would be, how do I get this exact formula to work? Exactly these areas have to be covered and cannot be changed, otherwise everything else is broken.

EDIT: Added example spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdTSZAfGTpoeun3k2qqkDMG1jnaUaSz6wgSf2heIIDI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: When you say the checkbox in I16:I, do you mean there is one checkbox, or many? Also, when you say "if the name matches in H16:H from G8" does this mean that the cell G8 contains many names? -- also see this for more info on A1 notation https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation

Comment: there are more then one for both questions. this will be auto increment with a form of questions. see the screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/uia199

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic here. Also, are you sure you got the ranges and numbers right in your question? Your sheet doesn't look like it lines up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your ranges. Here's how `=SUMIFS()` works and then you'll see why you need to adjust the function.

`=SUMIFS()` looks for ranges and then applies the logic. So when you are telling the function to summarise `E9:E14` it interprets it as:

```
SUM(E9,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14)
```

provided the following conditions. The conditions will tell the function whether to include each of the components (i.e. `E9`,...,`E14`).

Whether a condition is met or not is decided using a simple boolean (true/false) array. This could for example be `I9:I14=FALSE` which is interpreted as the array

```
{IF(I9=FALSE),IF(I10=FALSE),...,IF(I14=FALSE)}
```

resulting in an array similar to this:

```
{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}
```

(assuming the conditions `I9`, `I10` and `I14` are met but not the other three. The same is done for the second condition (the values in column `H` being equal to the value in `G8`, resulting in another array similar to this:

```
{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}
```

(assuming that only the values in `H9`, `H12` and `H14` are equal to `G8`.

When the function compares the two condition arrays and returns an aggregate array similar to this:

```
{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}
```

because only for the first and the last value the conditions are met. Therefore the `=SUM` function becomes like this:

```
SUM(E9,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,E14)
```

where `FALSE = 0` so it returns

```
=SUM(E9,E14)
```

**Here's where you get into trouble**

You try to pass the function conditional arrays that are of a different size to the sum array (`E9:E14`), in effect asking it to compare apples and the age of your neighbour. What you need to do is to create the calculation you have in column `E` in a new column in rows `24` down and use that as the sum range in `=SUMIFS()`.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I'll try your solution.